# How is it permissible for a Jewish slave to marry a Canaanite slavewoman?

Tags: gentiles, vaeschanan, slave-serve-eved-avadim, intermarriage, mishpatim

In Shemot, [chapter 21 verse 4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/showrashi/true/aid/9882#v=4), we learn that a master can give his Jewish slave a Canaanite slavewoman to bear the master slave children:

> If his master gives him a wife, and she bears him sons or daughters,
>   the woman and her children shall belong to her master, and he shall go
>   out alone.

Rashi says that this verse could only refer to a Canaanite slavewoman.

Then in Devarim, [chapter 7 verse 3](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9971#v=3), we learn:

> You shall not intermarry with them; you shall not give your daughter
>   to his son, and you shall not take his daughter for your son.

The two verses seem to contradict each other. Do we say that in the case of a Jewish slave, there is an exception where he is permitted to have relations with the Canaanite woman?

Comment: A canaanite slave is not a non-Jew. They are half-converted.

Comment: That changes things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rashi you quote is from the Mekhilta. The Ramban, too, holds that this verse can only refer to a Canaanite woman (see his commentary in which he disputes Rashi somewhat).

The pesuqim discuss an 'Ivri who stole and is subsequently being sold by a Beit Din. The Kli Yaqar (21:4) explains that, if the 'eved was married previously married, the master is liable to support the 'eved's family. For this, the Torah gives the master a chance to beget children from the female Canaanite slave.

As a side note, the Gemara (Qiddushin 14B) quotes a beraita which states that only a slave who stole, and was subsequently sold by a Beit Din, can be given a female Canaanite slave.

Comment: The Artscroll commentary says the same thing, but what do we do about the contradiction?

Comment: Artscroll brings the kli Yakar?

Comment: Also the passuk in Mishpatim is a פרט